# how to set a password on a rar file

Tags: c#, windows, winrar

I set a password on a rar file like this :

```
rar.exe a backup.rar c:\files -p123 -p- -k
```

this code set a password on my rar file and add `file` to it , but i do not know what is my password.
this is my C# code :

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\Rar.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"a backup.rar c:\files -p123 -p- -k";
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Please provide a link to the command-line switches available for the `rar.exe` that you're using, but in some Google searching, I found this:

> -p[password]   Set password
>
> -p-            Do not query password

Given that you have `-p123`, your password should be "123".

Comment: That problem was about 3 month ago , my problem did not solve and i could understand what happened , but any way you are right :) thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which works well:

```
C:\Program Files\WinRAR>rar a -hpabc h:\abc.rar c:\pdf
```

So you can follow the example in your codes.

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("a -hp{0} {1} {2}", your password, Destination, SourceFile);
p.Start();
```